# How to disable scroll event of listbox after the keydown or keypress event?

Tags: vb.net, listbox

Programming language is vb.net

Answer (score 0):

You could extend the ListBox class and then override the part of the class that throws the Scroll event.

EDIT: Do you want the Scroll event not to be thrown or do you actually not want the ListBox itself to scroll?

This might work - I cant test it here tho... Also you'll need to port to vb.net

```
public class BetterListBox : ListBox { 
  // WM_VSCROLL message constants
  private const int WM_VSCROLL = 0x0115;
  protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {
    // Trap the WM_VSCROLL message to generate the Scroll event
    if (m.Msg != WM_VSCROLL) {
       base.WndProc(ref m);
    }

}
```

Comment: I do want the scroll event to be thrown after the keydown or keypress event

Comment: can you please provide me the code or explain it on how to extend the listbox class and override the appropriate event ?

Comment: You said you want to disable the scroll event in your question but then below you say you want the scroll event to be thrown?  Can you explan your scenario a bit more clearly?

Comment: Sorry I want to  say 

I do not want the scroll event to be thrown after listbox  keydown or keyup event

Comment: I have tried it but it is giving me errors

Two Errors

1) 'ListBox' is a 'namespace' but is used like a 'type'
2)  The type or namespace name 'Message' could not be found

and can you please provide the same in vb.net

Comment: Dont have Visual Studio anymore sorry can't help you

Comment: I have Fixed the error and have converted the code to vb.net
code is here
Public Class BetterListBox
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.ListBox
    ' WM_VSCROLL message constants
    Private Const WM_VSCROLL As Integer = &H115
    Protected Overloads Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As Message)
        ' Trap the WM_VSCROLL message to generate the Scroll event
        If m.Msg <> WM_VSCROLL Then
            MyBase.WndProc(m)
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
But it is not working as required 
Can you please tell me?